# Having a hard time understanding bootstrap 3 column classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to go back to the basics and really wanting to understand the Bootstrap 3 column classes.

I have noticed a lot of sites (templates) that use either `col-sm-*` or `col-md-*` classes, rarely using a mixture of them or including the `col-lg-*` classes.

Can someone explain the proper way to build with "mobile first" in mind using the out of the box classes assembled in bootstrap 3?

Comment: The sm, md and lg bits refer to where it breaks based on screen size. For instance, a class of `col-sm-3`, the element will have 3 columns from small screens on up. Adding a `col-lg-2` class would mean at large sizes, the element would take up two columns

Answer (score 3):

The reason they may not use both the `col-sm-*` or `col-md-*` classes together on the same div is because they may not need those items to restructure differently to the [viewport sizes those levels represent](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

The reason for this is because any viewport widths that "bleed" into the next tier (say from sm to md) will simply retain what was defined at the previous, smaller tier, whereas any viewport width bellow that tier's minimum (say from md to sm) will simply stack the columns to be the full width of the page.

View this example in your browser to get an idea of what's going on.

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 green">.col-lg-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 green">.col-lg-8</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 green">.col-lg-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 green">.col-lg-4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 green">.col-lg-4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 green">.col-lg-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 green">.col-lg-6</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 green">.col-lg-6</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 orange">.col-md-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 orange">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 orange">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 orange">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 orange">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 orange">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 orange">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 orange">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 yellow">.col-sm-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 yellow">.col-sm-8</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 yellow">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 yellow">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 yellow">.col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 yellow">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 yellow">.col-sm-6</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 yellow">.col-sm-6</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 blue">.col-xs-1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 blue">.col-xs-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 blue">.col-xs-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 blue">.col-xs-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 blue">.col-xs-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 blue">.col-xs-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 blue">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 blue">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```

Gradually widen the preview window, and as it gets wider you'll notice the structure pops in for each tier as you enter its minimum viewport width.

As you can see, **it's not necessary to include all four tiers if your layout isn't going to change drastically from one viewport width to the next**. Anything higher than the maximum you've provided will sipmly remain, while anything smaller will simply cause your divs to stack for a more mobile friendly view. If your layout won't change at all from the smallest to the largest tiers? Simply use the xs tier and no others.

Here's another Bootply that provides an example of how the columns will completely restructure themselves as you go from a mobile view to higher viewport widths.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
}

.first {
  background-color: black;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
}

.third {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="first col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="second col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="third col-lg-3 visible-lg-inline"></div>
```

Run the code snippet and expand the preview window so it's full, then play with the width of your browser window. You'll see how everything restructures itself based on the viewport width.

Finally, you may want a div to be 3 columns wide on large and medium displays, but only 2 columns wide on ones in the small or extra small tiers. That's when you'd define a div as such:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2"></div>
```

This way on viewport widths of 992 pixels or higher, that div will be 3 columns wide, where as from 991 pixels wide and lower it'll only be 2 columns wide.

I hope this gives you a general understanding of how the grid system and responsive layout works in Bootstrap. Definitely read [the documentation for the grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), and it'll tell you pretty much everything you need to know. Seroiusly, Bootstrap's documentation is some of the best you'll find.

Comment: Nice effort on this answer :)

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to be thorough and thought maybe I was going into too much detail, but figured nah, I'll post this. I'm just surprised no one else got to it before I did. :D

Answer (score 0):

Mobile-first concept has been imagined and used before Bootstrap. So if you understand the concept, you'll understand how to use Bootstrap column classes.

---

So, how to simply define mobile-first concept?

- your website **must** be mobile-friendly without any media-queries
- you **must** write your media-queries from the smallest width, to the largest

Let's take this example, where you've got 4 different sizes:

```
body { background: green; }
@media (min-width: 768px)  { body { background: yellow; } }
@media (min-width: 990px)  { body { background: orange; } }
@media (min-width: 1280px) { body { background: red; } }
```

You can see media-queries are written in order of resolution size. **This point is essential**, as the code written in a media-query will override the previous one. Here's what happends if you don't respect this order:

```
@media (min-width: 1280px) { body { background: red; } }
@media (min-width: 990px)  { body { background: orange; } }
body { background: green; }
@media (min-width: 768px)  { body { background: yellow; } }
```

Let's use a resolution of 1000px-width:

- Is it larger than 1280px? No: *do nothing*.
- Is it larger than 990px? Yes: *use orange*.
- *Use green*
- Is it larger than 768px? Yes: *use yellow*.

Finally, our screen is yellow, whereas it should have been orange.

---

Let's get back to Bootstrap!
And let's say you need a template with:

- 1 column on mobiles (1 x 12)
- 2 columns on tablets and desktop (2 x 6)
- 1 columns on widescreens (1 x 12)

You're first attempt seems to has been this one:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
```

**This is perfectly valid.** But you can shorten this code.

Here's what you're asking to Bootstrap (remember classes are written in their order of resolution size, in Bootstrap code):

- #1 "Bootstrap, my dear... First of all, use 12 columns for this element!"
- #2 "Now, use 6 columns over 768px."
- #3 "Oh, and don't forget to use 6 columns over 970px!"
- #4 "Last thing, get back to 12 columns over 1170px, thanks."

You can see #2 and #3 means the same thing. You could simply ask to use 6 columns from 768px, and change you mind at 1170px:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
```

Second thing, your asking Bootstrap to use 12 columns by default, ie a 100% width. And what is the default width of an `display: block` element? Yep... 100%. You don't need #1 neither:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
```

---

To resume:

- you don't need a `.col-xx-xx` class if the previous one has the same amount of columns
- you don't need a `.col-xx-12` class if it's the smallest (xs < sm < md < xl) on your element.